# Jogl and JavaFX

Tags: java, opengl, javafx, jogl

I heared its possible to integrate Jogl into JavaFX with the NewtCanvasJFX but I can't get it to work.
I tried something like that.

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Jogl");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();

    //init Canvas
    final GLProfile glProfile = GLProfile.getDefault();
    final GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(glProfile);

    GLWindow glWindow = GLWindow.create(capabilities);

    NewtCanvasJFX glPanel = new NewtCanvasJFX(glWindow);
    glPanel.setWidth(300);
    glPanel.setHeight(300);

    StackPane openGLPane = new StackPane();
    openGLPane.getChildren().add(glPanel);

    glWindow.addGLEventListener(this);
}
```

I just need to get jogl and Javafx working together for a university project so if anyone has other solutions I would really appreciate them.

Comment: What happens if you run the program? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: It should open an empty window with an canvas object inside it. I get the error "Missing JavaFX application class" when i try to run it.

Comment: Do you have a main method?

Comment: of course: 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }

Comment: this just initializes javafx and runs the start function where all of the code from above is insde.

Comment: Do you try to run the correct class?

Comment: Yes I did run the correct class.

Comment: Is the error an exception or eg an error in the IDE?

Comment: It's not an exception. probably something related to the IDE but thats not the problem I think. I just need an way of connecting JavaFX and Jogl this code I posted is just some testing and needs a way of using newtCanvasJFS correctly.

Comment: You cannot run it because of the error, right?

Comment: Exactly but fixing this error wouldnt do the trick. I need someone who already integrated jogl into javafx with a correct code example

Comment: Then why aren't you asking this question on a JOGL forum?

Comment: I did but the forum is not really active.

Comment: @Sweck We'll answer you on the official JogAmp forum but you'll have to provide a lot more information: http://forum.jogamp.org/Jogl-and-JavaFX-td4040468.html By the way, next time, post a SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt get it to work with NewtCanvasJFX but I used gljpanel to combine jogl and javafx.

It is important that all jogl related stuff is inside SwingUtilities.invokeLater otherwise nothing will get rendered. You can just use the canvas to add an gleventlistener.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{ 
    root = new StackPane();

    final GLProfile glProfile = GLProfile.getDefault();
    final GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(glProfile);

    canvas = new GLJPanel(capabilities);

    swingNode = new SwingNode();

    root.getChildren().add(swingNode);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            swingNode.setContent(canvas);
            //jogl stuff here           
        }
    });


    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX OpenGL");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1920, 1080));
    primaryStage.show();         
}
```

Comment: It works with NewtCanvasJFX, I gave you a small example: http://forum.jogamp.org/Jogl-and-JavaFX-tp4040468p4040518.html